# How to capture a group of types in std::variant by using std::visit?

Tags: c++, c++17, fsm

To implement finite state machine (FSM),
I'm trying to capture the types defined in std::variant.

However, the thing that I want to achieve fails to capture the type.

To provide scenario, I borrow the examples from [here](http://www.vishalchovatiya.com/state-design-pattern-in-modern-cpp/)

```
#include <optional>
#include <variant>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
    /* ---------------------------------  Events ------------------------------------------ */
    struct EventConnect { string m_address; };
    struct EventConnected { };
    struct EventDisconnect { };
    struct EventTimeout { };
    using Event = variant<EventConnect, EventConnected, EventDisconnect, EventTimeout>;
    /* ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    /* ---------------------------------  States ------------------------------------------ */
    struct Idle { };
    struct Connecting {
        string                      m_address;
        uint32_t                    m_trial = 0;
        static constexpr uint8_t    m_max_trial = 3;
    };
    struct Connected { };
    using State = variant<Idle, Connecting, Connected>;
    using StateState = variant<Connecting, Connected>;
    /* ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    /* -------------------------------  Transitions ---------------------------------------- */
    struct Transitions {
        optional<State> operator()(StateState &, const EventConnected &) {
            cout << "HELLO WORLD" << std::endl;
            return Connected{};
        }
        optional<State> operator()(Idle &, const EventConnect &e) {
            cout << "Idle -> Connect" << endl;
            return Connecting{e.m_address};
        }
        // optional<State> operator()(Connecting &, const EventConnected &) {
        //     cout << "Connecting -> Connected" << endl;
        //     return Connected{};
        // }
        optional<State> operator()(Connecting &s, const EventTimeout &) {
            cout << "Connecting -> Timeout" << endl;
            return ++s.m_trial < Connecting::m_max_trial ? nullopt : optional<State>(Idle{});
        }
        optional<State> operator()(Connected &, const EventDisconnect &) {
            cout << "Connected -> Disconnect" << endl;
            return Idle{};
        }
        template <typename State_t, typename Event_t>
        optional<State> operator()(State_t &, const Event_t &) const {
            cout << "Unkown" << endl;
            return nullopt;
        }
    };
    /* ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    template <typename StateVariant, typename EventVariant, typename Transitions>
    struct Bluetooth {
        StateVariant m_curr_state;
        void dispatch(const EventVariant &Event)
        {
            optional<StateVariant> new_state = visit(Transitions{}, m_curr_state, Event);
            if (new_state)
                m_curr_state = *move(new_state);
        }
        template <typename... Events>
        void establish_connection(Events... e) { (dispatch(e), ...); }
    };
    int main() {
        Bluetooth<State, Event, Transitions> bl;
        bl.establish_connection(EventConnect{"AA:BB:CC:DD"},
                                EventTimeout{},
                                EventConnected{},
                                EventDisconnect{});
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
```

Here, the problem is that `visit` fails to visit states defined in `StateState`.

To be specific, the function,

```
optional<State> operator()(StateState &, const EventConnected &) {
  cout << "HELLO WORLD" << std::endl;
  return Connected{};
}
```

is not called.

It seems that because the state `Connecting` is also defined in `StateState`, `visit` should visit the function overloaded by `StateState`. What is the main reason that prevents the function from being visited?

How to enable `visit` to visit States defined in `StateState`?

Comment: Can you provide an [mcve]?

Comment: What do you mean by `although cur_state is the type defined in GroupY`?  In your posted code, `cur_state` is a `std::variant<GroupX>`, so it has no `GroupY` to vist.

Comment: `cur_state` is a `std::variant<std::variant<StateA, StateB, StateC, StateD>>`. Was that intentional? `visit` won't "recurse" into that...

Comment: @aschepler Sorry, it is GroupX cur_state. I'll reopen the post after I correctly modified the example

Comment: Again, please provide a [mre]. When I tried to make one from this, the library tells me "std::visit requires the visitor to have the same return type for all alternatives of a variant": https://godbolt.org/z/b45hfMzKE

Comment: @aschepler Now, added the reproducible examples and questions.

Comment: `operator()(StateState&, const EventConnected&)` can't be called here: there's no existing `StateState` object already, and a temporary `StateState` object could be created, but can't bind to a non-const lvalue reference.